# Video is in low fps when playing on TextureView

Tags: android, video, textureview

I'm creating video filter for Android app, so I'm using `TextureView` to play video and filter on its `SurfaceTexture`.
But the FPS of video's always lower than original(30fps).

As I checked on Galaxy S3, `onSurfaceTextureUpdated()` only enter 5~8 times per sec although having filter or not. But on stronger device, as Samsung Galaxy J, it could increase to 10~13 times per sec

Note that this video load from SD card.

Does someone know the reason?

```
mVideoPlayer.reset();
mVideoPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mVideoPlayer.setDataSource(mVideoPath);
mVideoPlayer.setSurface(new Surface(surfaceTexture));
mVideoPlayer.setLooping(true); mVideoPlayer.prepareAsync();
mVideoPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {mp.start(); }
});
```

Comment: Is it faster on a SurfaceView? i.e. are you sure that it's the TextureView causing the bottleneck? How are you configuring the MediaPlayer?

Comment: Yes, it's faster on a SurfaceView. But I need to use TextureView for filtering purpose. I 've keep only Video playing but it's still in low fps

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After checked with more devices, I found the main reason cause this issue is memory.
So I finish previous activity and release data before go to this activity.
Then the FPS of video increase to 10 + on S3.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

If the video frame is being accessed from software, then the data has to be copied a couple of times, and that will kill your FPS.

If you send the video directly to the Surface associated with the TextureView, you won't see a slowdown, but you will also have no opportunity to filter it.  ([Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika) has video players based on SurfaceView and TextureView, with no noticeable difference in performance.  SurfaceView is slightly more efficient, but not dramatically so.)

To get real-time filtering at 30fps you can use the GPU, as in [this example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kH9kCP2T5Gg), though there are limits to what you can do with that.